# HTTP REQUEST via ENC28J60 ethercard.h (Arduino Mega2560)

Tags: arduino

We would like to send a http request with ethercard.h.
But when we doing this

```
ether.browseUrl(PSTR("GET /"), "", website, my_callback);
```

We get a 400 bad request answer.

We would like to test http request like:
-POST
-HEAD
-PUT
-DELETE
-TRACE
-OPTIONS

But it seems only this is working:

```
ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/"), "", website, my_callback);
```

but why?

Comment: When you start deleting, why did you stop?

Answer (score 0):

For GET request you don't need to make a special definition. All requests are GET in default. That's why your request works without any definition. So i can share with you a POST request example. You can proceed from here:

```
Stash::prepare(PSTR("POST http://$F/$F.csv HTTP/1.0" "\r\n"
                "Host: $F" "\r\n"
                "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n"
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n"
                "\r\n"
                "$H"),
    website, PSTR(PATH), website, stash.size(), sd);
```

It even has a link to its explanation.  [POST Request Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791876/sending-http-post-request-with-arduino-and-enc28j60-ethernet-lan-network-module)